# Dense_rank order by on more than 999 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

We just found a weird behavior on Oracle Database

```
select dense_rank() over (order by val) rank, val
from (
  select lpad('a', 998, 'a') || '0' val from dual
  union all
  select lpad('a', 998, 'a') || '1' val from dual
);
```

Will return as expected :

```
RANK |VAL       
-----|-----------------
1    |aaaa[...]aaaaa0
2    |aaaa[...]aaaaa1
```

**But then we add 1 character**

```
select dense_rank() over (order by val) rank, val
from (
  select lpad('a', 999, 'a') || '0' val from dual
  union all
  select lpad('a', 999, 'a') || '1' val from dual
);
```

**And the result is unexpected :**

```
RANK |VAL       
-----|-----------------
1    |aaaa[...]aaaaa0
1    |aaaa[...]aaaaa1
```

*So I have to write :*

```
select dense_rank() over (order by val, substr(val, 999, 999)) rank, val
from (
  select lpad('a', 999, 'a') || '0' val from dual
  union all
  select lpad('a', 999, 'a') || '1' val from dual
);
```

**Can someone explain why this happen ?** **How to prevent it ?** *thanks*

Comment: I don't see this behaviour in Oracle11g as you mentioned. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=758c4ae9e7179d598849355d414d01f6

Comment: Works fine for me on `11.2.0.4.0`

Comment: I don't see this behavior on Oracle 12.2.0.1 either. What is your Oracle version? And what is your interface to the DB (SQL Developer? Toad? Simple SQL\*Plus? Something else?)

Comment: I confirm, wrong results in versions 10.2.0.4 and 11.2.0.1. And [here](https://oracleblog.org/working-case/bug-issues-known-to-cause-wrong-results/) I see something about bug 12647744, *DENSE_RANK returns wrong results* corrected in 11.2.0.4. Don't know more details.